# Passing a file content as command line parameter within a Makefile

Tags: makefile, parameter-passing, casperjs

For publishing webpages to wordpress I use casperjs in the following way, reading two parameters from file: the new webpage and the password.

```
casperjs tools/wordpresspublish.js 1 "$(< html/數1.html)" $(< tools/wppwd)
```

That works fine from the command line. Now I try to do the same in a Makefile:

```
.1.publ: 數1.html
   casperjs tools/wordpresspublish.js 1 "$(cat html/數1.html)" $(cat tools/wppwd)
   touch .1.publ
```

It seems to interpret the $ in a different way.

How can I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` character by writing it twice, like this :

```
casperjs tools/wordpresspublish.js 1 "$$(< html/數1.html)" $$(< tools/wppwd)
```

Also note that there is another character that has to be escaped : `#`. To escape it type `\#`.

Comment: Escaping seems to work, but it doesn't load the files. Both files seem to be empty, when I invoke the command in the makefile. I tried absolute paths ( /home/name/Development/2064/html/數1.html ) with the same result.

Comment: I found out: I have to write "cat" instead of "<" in the $( ) Then it works. I changed it in the question.